# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'unpack'

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I am trying to run a `lstm` model using tfLearn and I get this error:

```
File "...city_names.py", line 16, in <module>
g = tflearn.lstm(g, 256, activation='relu', return_seq=True)
File "...\tflearn\layers\recurrent.py", line 197, in lstm
inference = tf.unpack(inference)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'unpack'
```

with the following line:

```
g = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, maxlen, len(char_idx)])
```

These are the lines of code:

```
path = "US_cities.txt"
maxlen = 20
X, Y, char_idx = textfile_to_semi_redundant_sequences(path, seq_maxlen=maxlen, redun_step=3)
g = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, maxlen, len(char_idx)])
g = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, maxlen, len(char_idx)])
```

Comment: In tf 1.0, there's no `unpack`. You may want to use `unstack` instead.

Comment: so the file `recurrent.py` has not been updated. Do you know where I can get the updated codes?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration

Comment: @soloice, i tried upgrading tflearn according to the link you provided. But on running my code, it just opened a pandora's box of errors as there is lots to be upgraded in the library. Anyway, just mark your answer in the solution, I mark it  correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In tf 1.0, there's no `unpack`. You may want to use `unstack` instead.
To upgrade previous code, you can refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration.
But I don't know if there's a tool for updating an entire deep learning library such like tflearn = =

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and installed the latest ('bleeding edge') version of TFLearn and I did not get the 'unpack' attribute error anymore with TensorFlow 1.0 .

I used the following command in terminal to install **TFLearn 0.3**:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn.git
```

This is according to instructions on the TFLearn [GitHub page](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn#installation%22Github%20Page%22).